# Out-of-Equilibrium Macroeconomic Dynamics using Differential Equations

Tags: dynamic-optimization, real-business-cycles, difference-equations

> My OP below asks about the *RBC* model, but I am actually interested in any out-of-equilibrium macroeconomic model; CGE, DSGE or whatever the correct nomenclature is.

The *Real Business Cycle* model is a standard equilibrium model in macro-economics. There are various [versions](http://www.sfu.ca/%7Ebkrauth/econ808/808_lec5.pdf), but most consider a representative consumer and a representative firm. The consumer has to decide on a level of consumption, labour supply and investment so as to maximise utility. The firm maximises profits by deciding on a level of product output, labour demand and capital.

The model is usually solved by specifying equilibrium conditions and using [Langrange Multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) to solve for the steady-state. Sometimes, [technological shocks](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/4770/simulating-real-business-cycle) are added to the model, which result in changes in the equilibrium. As discussed [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/16434/looking-for-discussion-on-equilibrium-vs-dynamic-models-in-econometrics/), such movements of the equilibrium are what most economists consider '*dynamics*'.

In this question, I am using the term '*dynamics*' differently. I would like to create a simple *Real Business Cycle* model using differential equations. I would like to specify the behaviour of the consumer and the firm and show that the steady-state is reached *without* specifying any equilibrium conditions.

I realise I would need to make additional [assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replicator_equation) concerning the [time-dynamics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/15566/can-linear-supply-demand-equilibria-be-understood-as-a-feedback-control-process) of the model, e.g. that the rate of change of consumption is equal to the marginal utility w.r.t. consumption, $\frac{d}{dt} C = \frac{d}{dC} U$.

Such simple models must surely exist. Ultimately, a dynamic model must yield the identical steady-state to the standard version. I would like to learn how to *translate* equilibrium models to dynamic models using differential equations. Could anyone recommend an online tutorial, similar to [this](http://faculty.econ.ucdavis.edu/faculty/kdsalyer/LECTURES/Ecn235a/Linearization/ugfinal.pdf) but the non-equilibrium, dynamic version?

Comment: Do you want to reach "the" steady state in the sense of an optimal state, or just some where things don't move anymore in the absence of shocks, ie. a fixed point?

Comment: I guess that, under concave utility/profit curves, there is only 1 equilibrium, right? I am not necessarily looking for the _socially_ optimal state, though I believe in simple models the _socially_ optimal and the _competitive_ equilibrium coincide, right? Indeed, I am looking for a fixed-point equilibrium, in the game theory sense.

Comment: Basically what you described is what a phase diagram does: solving a system of differential (or difference) equations without finding the explicit solution, but just pointing out that a saddle path that leads to the steady state exists. The Ramsey model, if you just draw the phase diagram, is indeed what you are looking for.